# Question on elementary set theory notation

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation, real-numbers, natural-numbers, constants

Consider the set $A=\{n\ a \}$ where $a>0$ is a constant and $n \in \mathbb{N}$

**How shall we write this set $A$ in set theory?**

If we write it as $A=\{n\ a\ \backslash n \in \mathbb{N}, a>0 \}$ or $A=\{n\ a\ / n \in \mathbb{N}, a>0 \}$ will it mean just one set or a set of infinite sets?

Comment: $\{na\}$ is just a single set with a single element, which depends on the "external" constants $a$ and $n$.

Comment: $n$ is not a constant. $A=\{a,2a,3a,4a,....\}$

Comment: The set-builder notation you're trying to achieve is `\{ na \mid n \in \mathbb{N} \}`, producing $\{na \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- If both $n$ and $a$ are fixed, then the set is , the singleton $\{na\}$
- If $a$ is fixed and $n \in \Bbb N$ is a varying quantity, then the set is $\{na: n \in \Bbb N\}=\{a,2a,3a,\cdots\}$

In both cases, $A$ is *one* set with cardinality $1$ and infinite(of course, $\aleph_0)$ respectively!

Comment: Well, $n$ is not fixed.Your second option is correct. Anyway how can we write the information about $a$, i.e. $a>0$ in the set notation?

Comment: You already fixed $a>0$, so it is also better to write the set by $$A_a=\{na: n \in \Bbb N\}$$ which means the element $a$ is fixed is understood

Comment: or just write $$A=\{na: n=1,2,3, \cdots\;\text{and}\;a>0\;\text{is fixed} \}$$

Answer (score 2):

You can also write it as $a\Bbb N$.

Comment: This especially comes in handy when you have more sets of this kind and do some operations on them!